# Как форматировать число с плавающей точкой в PHP?

Tags: php

Вместо
1.027E-5

Получить
0.00001039

Comment: Уверен, что дубль вопроса где-то валялся. Наверное теперь этот будет)

Comment: ТС, примите один из ответов

Comment: Нет, ТС, отметьте свой вопрос как дубликат :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычной функцией [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) это можно сделать.

Проблема только с тем чтобы "угадать" сколько символов после запятой нужно вывести, к примеру в вашем случае это 8 символов:

```
$number = 1.027E-5;
$converted = number_format($number, 8);
echo $converted; //0.00001027
```

Но если будет другое число то в конце могут быть цифры 0 лишние, для этого убираем их через `rtrim`:

```
$number = 1.027E-5;
$converted = number_format($number, 10);
echo $converted; //0.0000102700
echo rtrim($converted, 0); //0.00001027
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$a = 1.027E-5;
$r = number_format ( $a,10);
echo $r;
```

Проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a886f71bdf7fc7ed97bde3b79983333efe636626

Подробнее про number_format читаем http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php